# WPF Changes not reflecting, Only on cleaning solution changes are reflected

Tags: c#, wpf

Each time i am making any change to the code or xaml, the changes are not getting reflecting . Each time i had to clean and rebuild and run, then the changes are affected. Not sure of this wierd behavior. Just for changing height of a text box as well.

Any solution or setting for this?

Comment: Is the application split up into multiple projects, where some of the controls are in separate DLL's (projects)?

Comment: Sounds like you are not saving your changes and building the project, either that, you actually have an compile error thats not being displayed.  Because a sucessful build would wipe the existing build files for all projects.

Comment: The actual is split in to multiple projects, But i am working on an individual project.  , There are no build errors and i am saving after my changes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that any and all projects in the solution are is sync with each other in "Configuration Manager"

Build/Configuration Manager ...

They should all be targeting the same platform.